# How to get lighting in the shower like this?

Tags: lighting, bathroom, shower, light, recessed-lighting

I'm remodeling my bathroom and I'd like to know how to get a lighting effect as seen in these photos. To get this, do you basically drop the ceiling to create a soffit over the shower, with a rope light or recessed light in the non-soffited part? How would you do this?

[image: lighting]

Comment: whatever lighting fixture was used will need to be listed for a wet location, I have done similar with trough lights inset in the ceiling. The only problem I found with those was they are a nightmare to remove the covers.